# Custom View with Two-Way Databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I have a custom view that extends LinearLayout and inflates a Layout which contains a couple of Views.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/voice_edittext"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Add answer here"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/microphone_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_mic_black_24dp"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/delete_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel_black_24dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I now want to two-way bind the text value of the Edittext when I use this view, like this:

```
<com.sunilson.quizcreator.presentation.views.EditTextWithVoiceInput
                android:id="@+id/form_question"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                app:editTextValue="@={viewModel.observableText}"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

For this I created some Binding Adapters

```
@BindingAdapter("editTextValueAttrChanged")
fun setListener(editTextWithVoiceInput: EditTextWithVoiceInput, listener: InverseBindingListener) {
    editTextWithVoiceInput.voice_edittext.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
            listener.onChange()
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}
        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}
    })
}

@BindingAdapter("editTextValue")
fun setTextValue(editTextWithVoiceInput: EditTextWithVoiceInput, value: String?) {
    if (value != editTextWithVoiceInput.voice_edittext.text.toString()) editTextWithVoiceInput.voice_edittext.setText(value)
}

@InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "editTextValue")
fun getTextValue(editTextWithVoiceInput: EditTextWithVoiceInput): String? {
    return editTextWithVoiceInput.voice_edittext.text.toString()
}
```

This is the code of the view:

```
class EditTextWithVoiceInput(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : LinearLayout(context, attributeSet) {

    init {
        val inflater = context?.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.voice_edittext, this, true)

        view.microphone_button.setOnTouchListener { p0, p1 ->
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The problem now is that when the Fragment containing the view is started, I get this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.sunilson.quizcreator, PID: 12627
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.sunilson.quizcreator.presentation.views.EditTextWithVoiceInput.setTag(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                  at com.sunilson.quizcreator.databinding.FragmentAddQuestionBinding.<init>(FragmentAddQuestionBinding.java:112)
                  at android.databinding.DataBinderMapperImpl.getDataBinder(DataBinderMapperImpl.java:15)
                  at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.bind(DataBindingUtil.java:199)
                  at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:130)
                  at android.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:95)
                  at com.sunilson.quizcreator.presentation.SingleActivity.fragments.AddQuestionFragment.AddQuestionFragment.onCreateView(AddQuestionFragment.kt:34)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2425)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1460)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2623)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2410)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2365)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2272)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:733)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:180)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:835)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You're missing the stacktrace. It'll tell you where you'll find the issue.

Comment: @tynn sorry, I added it to the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so my problem was that my custom view had incorrectly implemented the constructor functions. As I inflate this view in XML, I needed the constructor where I get passed the Attributeset to pass that Attributeset to the super constructor, which I did not do. Without that, my view had no attributes and could not be found via it's ID etc.

Now I have two constructors, depending on if I inflate from XML or code:

```
constructor(context: Context, optional: Boolean) : super(context) {
        ...
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributeSet) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: i'm already using this JvmOverloads for my constructor, but still having this issue. :(
any idea? 

CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)